# Galileo discovery of vacuum

Tags: biographical-details

I want to know how he thought that when his siphon could not raise water more than 10m it may be because of vacuum?
Please refer the link below https://wikivisually.com/wiki/Gasparo_Berti

Comment: Hi!  When you pose a question like this, please provide some background and some references for your claims.  In addition, are you asking about a "discovery" of vacuum and air pressure, or about an apparent estimate of max vacuum pressure?

Comment: It was not his siphon but Balliani's, and the mechanism of siphon was associated with vacuum since Aristotle. Galileo was not particularly original, he simply quantified Aristotle's *horror vacui*  into *resistenza del vacuo* or *forza del vacuo*. The idea was that vacuum's resistance to being created produced a force that held the water, see [Wikipedia's Barometer: History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometer#History). This was 14 years before Torricelli dispensed with the "force of vacuum", and came up with the modern explanation.